# Options menu items not working when Scroll view is used

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I created a XML file for menu and I am inflating it in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

The menu items are working fine in Lollipop device even with nested scrollview, but are not working (they are visible but I am not able to click on the items) in previous versions.

When I remove the scrollview they are working fine. But when I gave a padding of `?attr/colorPrimary` or more than that to the scrollview it is not working. Is there any problem with `NestedScrollView` or `ScrollView` with action bar? I need the scroll view. Where am I doing wrong?

activity layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <include layout="@layout/content_display_list" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
    android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:tint="#ffffff"
    app:backgroundTint="#86e384" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Menu XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.manisankarj.todolist.DisplayList">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_displaylist_past"
        android:title="Past Items"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_alarm"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Activity file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display_list, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. I just wrapped the entire `NestedScrollView` in a `FrameLayout` and the options menu items are now responding in pre-Lollipop devices.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/content_display_list" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

But I still do not understand why it behaved in such a way only on pre-Lollipop devices. May be a bug with the actionbar.